# Postgres "first" aggregation function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am aggregation a table using file ID field. Each file has a name which matched exactly one (his) file id.

```
select file_key, min(fullfilepath)
from table
group by file_key
```

Because I know the structure of the table, I know that I need ANY fullfilepath. The min and the max are ok, but it requires a lot of time.

I came across [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)) aggregation function which returns the first value. Unfortunately, this function takes a long time, because it scans the whole table. For example, this is very slow:

```
select first(file_id) from table;
```

What is the fastest way to do that? With or without aggregation function.

Comment: For the first query, try `select distinct on (file_key), file_key, fullfilepath from the_table order by file_key, fullfilepath` - that _might_ be faster then the `group by`

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_(aggregate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to make your first query with the `GROUP BY` clause faster, because it *has* to scan the whole table to find all groups.

Your second query can be made faster:

```
SELECT (
   SELECT file_id FROM "table"
   WHERE file_id IS NOT NULL
   LIMIT 1
);
```

There is no way to optimize the query as you wrote it, because the aggregate function is a *black box* to PostgreSQL.

Comment: You last statement is *usually* true. But PostgreSQL can optimize (and use an index), when it has a defined [`SORTOP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) (which min/max has).

Comment: That means that you can use the index for `SELECT min(field) FROM atable`, but not for `SELECT min(field) FROM atable GROUP BY anotherfield`. Think about it - *all different* values of `anotherfield` have to be identified, and how can an index help there? That requires a sequential or index scan over the whole table, and the table scan is usually cheaper there.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this will help performance but it may be useful if anyone actually wants a first agregate.

```
-- coaslesce isn't a function so make an equivalent function.
create function coalesce_("anyelement","anyelement") returns "anyelement"     
    language sql as $$ select coalesce( $1,$2 ) $$;

create aggregate first("anyelement") (sfunc=coalesce_, stype="anyelement");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    distinct on (file_key) 
    file_key, fullfilepath
from table
order by file_key
```

That will return one record for each file_key